# iOS TestFlight - External tester email addresses

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

When adding email addresses for external testers in TestFlight, does the email address of the tester **have** to be their registered Apple ID?  Or can it be any email address they can access on their iOS device?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be both - registered Apple ID email and not (in this case, Apple send invitation, and ask this user to create Apple id).

BUT if this email is already in iTunes Connect, you can't add this email. I faced with this problem with my client - they can't add my main email, because it is already connected to iTunes Connect account.

Comment: Just had my beta app approved so I could finally test this.  I can confirm the email address for external testers **does not** have to be the user's registered Apple ID.

Answer (score 4):

**No** it does. Even though it doesn't say anything about that in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35-SW6).

When you open TestFlight app, it ask to login with your AppleID or create new one.
But if person was able to download TestFlight from AppStore it means they have AppleID.

In the TestFlight app setting it says (click on AppleID)

> You can accept invites with your current AppleID, even if the invite email and the AppleId don't match

Comment: This is only true for Internal Testing which is not related to the question. For external testing you can invite any email address.

Comment: Is there a typo here? Should it say "No, it does not"?

Comment: This answer and comments raise more questions that they answer. Makes sense that one must have an appleid to download testflight. Everything else is a head scratcher. What does "no it does" mean? How can it be OK to use an appleid when the email is sent a different address? what does hefgi mean?